# Random trailing characters printing a string in C

Tags: c, arrays

Hi I am trying to create a char array consisting of only underscores and spaces.The function game takes in a char array and the creates a new array with all characters converted into underscores and spaces left as they are for example Stack would be _ _ _ _ _.

It does work upto a point I get all the underscores but I get random characters trailing at the end off the array i'm new to c so if anyone can see where ive gone wrong it would be much appreciated.

```
 int game(char p[])
{
int length = strlen(p);

int newLength = length * 2;
newLength = newLength +1;
char display[newLength];
InitializeArray(display,newLength);

for(int i = 0;i<=length-1;i++)
{

    if(p[i]==' ')
    {

        display[i*2]=' ';
    }
    else
    {
        display[i*2] = '_';
    }


}
}



int InitializeArray(char Array[], int Length)
{
   int i;

   for (i = 0; i < Length-1; i++) 
     {
      printf("%i",i);
      Array[i] = ' ';
     }
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure the `Length` in your 2 functions are same meaning, but it obvious that the condition in `for` is different(one is `<= `and the other is `<`). Is that why?

Answer (score 3):

Replace :

```
int InitializeArray(char Array[], int Length)
{
   int i;

   for (i = 0; i < Length-1; i++) 
     {
      printf("%i",i);
      Array[i] = ' ';
     }
 }
```

By :

```
int InitializeArray(char Array[], int Length)
{
   int i;

   for (i = 0; i < Length-1; i++) 
     {
      printf("%i",i);
      Array[i] = ' ';
     }
   Array[Length - 1] = '\0';
 }
```

Because all string need to be ended by the character '\0', it is a convention. What does it exist? To permit to developper to know where the string end.

If you need more informations, you are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Always terminate your strings with a '\0', or 0x00, character, this is the convention for identifying the end of a string (strlen, printf, etc, needs it).

Answer (score 1):

The array of characters must have a NULL character '\0' at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your purpose very well ,but I think the problem is about '\0'